# VBA, how to clear a cell after another cell is cleared that is part of an existing macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro I am using that fills in cell, "M", whenever data is entered in the adjacent cell in column "L".. I want to be able to have the data in cell "M" be cleared if the data in the adjacent "L" cell is deleted.

I have tried to review through stack for ideas but nothing is clicking with me..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim L As Range, M As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set L = Range("L:L")
    Set Inte = Intersect(L, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("B4")

        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I just need to know what I can add to this in order for this task to be completed.

Comment: Will you be changing more than 1 cell at a time or will it always be one cell?

Comment: `If IsEmpty(r) Then r.Offset(,1).ClearContents`?

Comment: Could be changing just 1 cell, but often it would be multiple cells in column L that will be getting cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an If to determine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim L As Range, M As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set L = Range("L:L")
    Set Inte = Intersect(L, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            If r.Value = "" Then
                r.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
            Else
                r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("B4")
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```